# How can I connect a Producer to an Actor?

Tags: kotlin, actor, kotlinx.coroutines

How can I connect a producer, created with the [`produce`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/produce.html)  coroutine builder, to an actor, created with the [`actor`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/actor.html) coroutine builder?

Basically, I'd like the send channel of the `producer` to be the receive channel of the `actor`. Is there a simple way to do that?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation allowing me to explicitly specify the channel to be used by the producer or actor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following definitions:

```
val producer = produce<T> { ... }
val actor = actor<T> { ... }
```

You can write the following code to launch a helper coroutine that sends all produced messages to your actor:

```
launch { producer.toChannel(actor) }
```

If you want to wait until this copying job is done, you can simply use `producer.toChannel(actor)` for your coroutine. `toChannel` is a terminal operation that waits until the processing is complete.